# reversible Turing machines

Tags: co.combinatorics, ds.dynamical-systems, computational-complexity, computability-theory, it.information-theory

Hello,
Let T be a Turing machine such that

1) it operates on the alphabet {0,1},

2) its set of states is A

3) the language it accepts is $L$ .

Does there exists a Turing machine S which also operates on the alphabet {0,1} and such that the language it accepts is L (the set of states might be different though) and such that, crucially, S is reversible?

By reversible I mean "the computational paths of S are disjoint". More precisely, the transition table of S gives rise to a map $K_S: \text{Tapes}\times B \to \text{Tapes} \times B$, where Tapes is the subset of the infinite product $\{0,1\}^Z$ consisting of those sequences which have a finite number of 1's, and B is the set of states of S. S is reversible iff, by definition, $K_S$ is injective on the set
$$
 \bigcup_{i=0}^\infty K_S^{i}(\text{Tapes}\times \{Initial \} ),
$$
where $Initial\in B$ is the initial state of S.

If the answer to the above question is "no" then what if we allow S to operate on an alphabet which is larger then {0,1}?

Comment: I'm voting to keep this question open because it was asked a long time ago, seems to have been answered satisfactorily, and I see no reason why anyone should seek closure unless they are on a deletion mission.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the method of the universal Turing machine, consider the Turing machine $S$ that on input $x$ simulates the computation of $T$ on $x$, and keeps track of the entire computation history. That is, $S$ writes down on the tape complete descriptions (tape contents, state, head position) of each successive step of the computation of $T$ on $x$. If eventually $S$ finds that $T$ accepts or rejects $x$, then $S$ should also accept or reject $x$.

This computation is reversible, since at any stage of the computation of $S$ on $x$, we can easily read off $x$ from the description of the first configuration, and so we know how $S$ started and therefore how we got to where we are.

Another way to do it would be the following: using a pairing function, regard the tape as two tapes, and then on input $x$, make a copy of $x$ on one of the tapes, and then with each step of simulated computation increment a counter on this tape (by adding one more $1$). This process leads to a reversible computation, since from any stage in the computation we can tell what the input was, and how many simulated steps have been performed. So we know where the computation came from.

These computation are reversible in the weaker sense that they can be reversed from the configurations that actually arise in computation, whereas your definition seems to require reversibility on all possible finite confgurations, even if these would not arise during an actual computation. Is that really what you want?

Comment: I don't think this answers the OP's intended question: he would like a finite increase of the state space (or perhaps the alphabet as well) which allows this.  You use the tape to track this, in a clearly unbounded manner.

Comment: My solution has only a finite increase in the state space (since the universal machine has only finitely many states), and no increase in the alphabet. Of course, it does use more of the tape, and the computations will take longer time. But the OP may object that my computations are only reversible on the configurations that arise in normal computation, and not necessarily on all possible configurations.

Comment: 1) My definition requires injectivy on the set $Y=\bigcup ...$, not on the whole set $\text{Tapes} \times B$. $Y$ is precisely the set of configurations which arise in the actual computation.

2) I insist on considering a Turing machine with just one tape.   

Comment: Lukasz, in this case, my answer seems to meet all your requirements. I had in mind that my algorithm would use just one tape. In any case, Turing machines with one tape can easily simulate Turing machines with multiple tapes---these computational models are well-known to have equal power. 

Comment: Joel, I'm still unhappy, but I admit your answer answers my question :-).

Let me informally say why I'm still unhappy. Suppose T' operates on {0,1,g}, where g is certain special symbol, but at the beginning T' is not given a tape with only 0's and the word written on it but rather a tape with a word written between two symbols g, and random entries elsewhere. Starting with the original T one can easily modify it and define T' in such a way that it ignores entries besides the two symbols g and so it accepts the word between two g's iff this word belongs to L. 
(TBC)

Comment: Now it seems to me that the process of copying the word g cannot be made irreversible.

The reason I'm interested in this kind of process is because it seems to me taht "preparing an infinite (or a long enough) tape with only 0's" is "expensive thermodynamically" :-). 

Still, I think I understood something thanks to your answer, so cheers :-).

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. You are right to pay attention to markers for end-of-input. When using just {0,1} as the alphabet, one usually must use unary form for input (that is, the number n represented as n consecutive 1s), rather than thinking of finite strings, since otherwise there is no way to tell when the input has ended. This unary input is what I meant by normal computation, but I notice that your definition of Tapes is more general than that for the starting configuration, and so my answer will not work in that more general setting. But it does work for the usual input form.

Comment: ...There is a way of coding more symbols into the {0,1} alphabet, just by operating two-cells-at-once. For example, by grouping them in twos, you really have four symbols: 00 01 10 11. This way, one can still perform computation on input strings, but one should set up the input tape to use only 00 and 01 (interpreted as 0 and 1 respectively) for the input, marked off by 11 at the ends, so that the machine knows when the input has finished. That is, if you set up your input to respect the coding, and then it is as though you have more symbols.

Comment: I understand your point now about the {0,1,g} example, and I think that this illustrates the difference between what I had called normal input and the situation you are thinking about, where the tape has extra random stuff on it. My algorithm wouldn't work on this example, even with the end-of-input markers and even if there is only finitely much extra stuff, since I need for the machine to be able to tell the entire input string in order to write down the computation history. This is not possible if the machine cannot tell when the total input ends (that is, the random stuff beyond the g's).

Comment: Do you know if the statement "This is not possible if the machine cannot tell when the total input ends (that is, the random stuff beyond the g's)." has been made into a precise theorem with a proof?

Comment: It is easy to prove. Suppose the machine could tell when the finitely many 1s end, and the all-0s start. Let the machine operate, but now change some 0 to 1 very far away, which the machine never looks at in that computation. The computation would behave just the same, since it never sees that cell, but get the wrong answer, since there was a 1 way out there.

Answer (score 5):

Well there are universal reversible Turing machines (RTMs), for example [1].
So you can simulate T with a universal RTM.
The resulting machine would be reversible and accept L.

---

[1] Kenichi Morita and Yoshikazu Yamaguchi, "A Universal Reversible Turing Machine" MCU2007

Answer (score 4):

I think your map *K<sub>S</sub>* also needs to take the position of the tape head as input, or am I missing something?

The classic paper [Logical reversibility of computation](http://www.dna.caltech.edu/courses/cs191/paperscs191/bennett1973.pdf) by C.H. Bennett defines reversible Turing machines as

> a finite set of n-tape quadruples, no two of which overlap either in domain or range

which should imply your notion of reversibility, assuming you allow an arbitrary alphabet instead of just Σ = {0, 1}.

Comment: By the way, if I recall correctly, Bennet’s construction is very similar to what Joel David Hamkins suggests in his answer.

Comment: As to the position, I consider $\\{0,1\\}^Z$ to mean the set of functions from Z (i.e. integers) to {0,1}, so the position is automatically encoded.

Unfortunately this paper gives an answer which is a Turing machine with more than one tape, which does not satisfy me. S should be a standard one-tape Turing machine.

Comment: Sorry, it should be "I consider {0,1}^Z..."

Answer (score 1):

[Vincent Danos](http://www.pps.jussieu.fr/~danos/) and [Samson Abramsky](http://www.comlab.ox.ac.uk/samson.abramsky/) have done interesting work on reversible computation using different models of computation. Some interesting papers include [General Reversibility](http://www.pps.jussieu.fr/~danos/pdf/abstran.pdf) and [A Structural Approach to Reversible Computation](http://www.comlab.ox.ac.uk/files/339/revised.pdf). The first is based on Milner's CCS; the second on Combinatorial Logic.

Comment: The link in the answer no longer works, but the paper V. Danos, J. Krivine, P. Sobociński: General reversibility can be found at DOI: [10.1016/j.entcs.2006.07.036](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.entcs.2006.07.036).